# amix filter in FFmpeg fails depending on the mp3 inputs

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3

In an android application I'm using amix filter to merge two mp3 files. Now, sometimes it works and sometime it gives an "out of memory" error depending of what pair of mp3 inputs it takes. I paste here the FFmpeg log for two different executions merging two different mp3 files.

This fails for out of memory:

```
Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/1.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 137 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0xb5b9f600] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 417.
Input #1, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/7.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:01.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/8.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> amix:input1
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Error while filtering: Out of memory
size=       5kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate= 105.0kbits/s speed=1.51x    
video:0kB audio:4kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.548245%
```

This works ok:

```
Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/2.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:01.36, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 195 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 195 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0xb5c5f600] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 417.
Input #1, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/4.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 143 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/esplode/8.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> amix:input1
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       7kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=  79.6kbits/s speed=1.45x    
size=      13kB time=00:00:01.33 bitrate=  77.0kbits/s speed=1.76x    
video:0kB audio:12kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.010969%
```

And this are the parameters I'm passing to FFmpeg:

```
[-i, input1, -i, input2, -filter_complex, amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[aout], -map, [aout], -ac, 2, -c:a, libmp3lame, -q:a, 9, outputmp3]
```

What is different in the two pairs of files so that one fails and the other works?

Comment: 1. Provide the complete console output/log from the command that doesn't work. 2. Provide the two inputs that don't work. 3. Try a recent version of `ffmpeg` from the git master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found out what was going on. When the first input is shorter than the second one it gives a `out of memory` error and the output is an mp3 file truncated when the first one ends, despite in the ffmpeg command I specified `duration=longest`. 
Solution in my case was just to calculate the longest input and set it as first. I also believe this is a bug of the ffmpeg version I'm using and I hope it has been corrected in the newer versions.